# Get values and column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a  pandas data frame that looks something like this:

```
data = {'1' : [0, 2, 0, 0], '2' : [5, 0, 0, 2], '3' : [2, 0, 0, 0], '4' : [0, 7, 0, 0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
df


    1   2   3   4
a   0   5   2   0
b   2   0   0   7
c   0   0   0   0
d   0   2   0   0
```

I know I can get the maximum value and the corresponding column name for each row by doing (respectively):

```
df.max(1)
df.idxmax(1)
```

How can I get the values and the column name for every cell that is not zero?
So in this case, I'd want 2 tables, one giving me each value != 0  for each row:

```
a 5
a 2
b 2
b 7
d 2
```

And one giving me the column names for those values:

```
a 2
a 3
b 1
b 4
d 2
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for `Series`, then filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html), [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and last [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) column or select columns by subset:

```
s = df.stack()
df1 = s[s!= 0].rename_axis(['a','b']).reset_index(name='c')
print (df1)
   a  b  c
0  a  2  5
1  a  3  2
2  b  1  2
3  b  4  7
4  d  2  2
```

---

```
df2 = df1.drop('b', axis=1)
print (df2)
   a  c
0  a  5
1  a  2
2  b  2
3  b  7
4  d  2

df3 = df1.drop('c', axis=1)
print (df3)
   a  b
0  a  2
1  a  3
2  b  1
3  b  4
4  d  2
```

---

```
df3 = df1[['a','c']]
print (df3)
   a  c
0  a  5
1  a  2
2  b  2
3  b  7
4  d  2

df3 = df1[['a','b']]
print (df3)
   a  b
0  a  2
1  a  3
2  b  1
3  b  4
4  d  2
```

Comment: Glad can help, nice day!